# Adding a constraint to a view in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible / practical to add a constraint (i.e., Primary Key or Index) to a view?

I am using SQL Server 2000 and the view queries multiple tables across 2 databases.

I know how to add a constraint to the tables that host/build the view.  Those indexes are there.  They just don't seem to carry over to the view.

Thought? Ideas? Suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: What problem are you having? Or are you imagining a problem that does not exist yet?

Answer (score 3):

If your views don't violate any of the long list of requirements, you *can* create a clustered index on your view in SQL Server 2000, and thus speed up queries quite a bit.

See:

- [SQL Team: Indexed Views in SQL Server 2000](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/indexed-views-in-sql-server-2000)
- [MSDN: Improving Performance with SQL Server 2000 Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902643%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Anything else isn't supported, as far as I know - if you want a constraint, you need to constrain the underlying base tables.

If you have a concrete problem with a view, maybe you need to explain in more detail. What do your base tables look like? What kind of data (and how much) is in there? What does your view definition look like? What are the queries you run against that view, and how does it behave - is it "just slow" or do you get wrong results, or what's the issue?